# Ways of restrict user based on user level in PHP

Tags: php, permissions, restrict, root

I have seen Joomla using many types of user access for the admin site. For example user, admin user, registered user and super user. The system actually know what type of user you are once we logged in. I'm trying to do the same thing for my web app. I need any suggestions on how this features can be achieved using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a user is in a database, you could have an column like `role` which would be user, admin, registered, and super.

Then in PHP you can use switch / if-condition blocks based on that `role` variable.